# Spring dispatcher-servet.xml config

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I've read [Spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html), and what thery says is

> Upon initialization of a DispatcherServlet, Spring MVC looks for a
>   file named [servlet-name]-servlet.xml in the WEB-INF directory of your
>   web application and creates the beans defined there, overriding the
>   definitions of any beans defined with the same name in the global
>   scope.

The thing is I used spring `myappContext.xml` which was loaded by `org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener`. Is it possible to use both `dispatcher`'s and my old configuration files in the application? I just wouldn't move all definition from the `myappContext.xml` config to `dispacther`'s config. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could import xml file into your dispatcher's bean xml file that way you won't have to copy all beans into single file

```
<import resource="classpath:/path/to/bean-defination.xml"/>
```